# Best way to insert large amounts of data from a WCF call into SQL

Tags: .net, wcf, sql-server-2008

I'm calling a third party web service that returns a large amount of XML (1000s of rows).  What is the best way to get the XML into an underlying SQL server 2008 R2 table.  At the moment I am retrieving the XML and deserializing into .NET class collections using the associated XSD.  I then iterate through the collection making multiple calls to a INSERT stored proc.  The performance isn't too bad but I'm sure there must be a quicker way to do this.  Should I be looking at SqlBulkCopy?  I've heard that LINQ-TO-SQL is slow when it comes to bulk inserts/updates.  Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [SQLXMLBulkLoad4](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/e219f893-02d6-4566-b77f-07d1993291bd/), that seems to handle bulk inserts of XML to sql server. I havent tried it myselfe, but its worth a try.

If that not working, then check out [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)
Using SqlBulkCopy I put 200.000 rows of data read from a file in about 4 seconds.

The following code takes a filename as argument, read all lines and transform  the lines to a datarow that is added to a datatable (The datatable has to have same format as the target table, Im using a strongly typed datatable in this case). When the datatable contains 1000 rows, I write it to the server with the WriteToServer method. Then empty the datatable and start over.

you could easy change it to transform rows from your xml-document instead.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Sub ParseFile(ByVal filename As String)
    Using BulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(My.Settings.DBConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
        BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Destinationtable"
        Dim TableDataSet As New MyDS.UserDataTable
        Try
            Using sr As StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(filename)
                Dim l As String = Nothing
                l = sr.ReadLine()
                If Not l Is Nothing Then AddToDS(l, TableDataSet)
                Do Until l Is Nothing
                    l = sr.ReadLine()
                    If Not l Is Nothing Then AddToDS(l, TableDataSet)
                    If TableDataSet.Rows.Count > My.Settings.BulkSize Then 'bulk copy every 1000 rows to db.
                        BulkCopy.WriteToServer(TableDataSet)
                        TableDataSet.Rows.Clear()
                    End If
                Loop
                If TableDataSet.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'write the rest
                    BulkCopy.WriteToServer(TableDataSet)
                    TableDataSet.Rows.Clear()
                End If
                sr.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Sub AddToDS(ByVal s As String, ByRef ds As MyDS.UserDataTable)
    'row should contain username + tab + carname
    Dim arr() As String = s.Split(vbTab)
    If arr.Count < 2 Then Exit Sub
    ds.AddUserRow(arr(0).Trim, arr(1).Trim)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that Stefan. I have seen quite a few code samples like this. Is this transactional i.e if one insert fails are all the previous row inserts rolled back? If not how can you make it transactional?

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is IDisposable - you should wrap it in a Using statement, like you did for your StreamReader.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is a all or nothing affair. It won't import some of the records and not others.

Comment: Graymatter, yes, it is important to read into the subject and understand exactly what the SqlBulkCopy does before using it. I recommend an hour on the msdn link and some googleing before put it in production. ;)

Comment: Myles J, I recommend reading this article, http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111109-1.aspx

Comment: The approach could be more simplified as SqlBulkCopy already has built-in batch behavior, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx

Comment: Martin, in my case I read a file that contains millions of rows. So my chunk-handeling purpose is to minimize memory usage. I think my clientcomputer would choke If I read in 4 millions of rows in a dataset in memory and then sent it to the server. ;)

Comment: Martin, but the batchsize in combination with UseInternalTransaction is worth reading up about.

Comment: What about using OPENXML in a proc and passing the XML directly over to the stored proc?  Any comments on the performance of OPENXML for bulk inserts?